# over-riding magento's PriceHtml generation - doesn't work on homepage

Tags: price, blocks, magento-1

I used an extension (Simple Product Pricing by Ayasoftware) to make it so that product pages and catalog listing pages show a "from:" price rather than £0.00 for configurable products, problem is that when I use the same function that I use in the listing/view pages on the homepage - it still shows £0.00

The code for displaying the price on the homepage is as follows:

```
$productBlock= Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

As you can see I create an instance of `catalog/product_price` and use its `getPriceHtml` function to get the price, so why does it display a different output than when I use it on the product listing and view pages?

On those pages I can just use `$this` as they extend the class with the method in but even if I do it the `createBlock` way (exactly as I have done on the homepage) then it still shows what I want - so I would pose they are using the same function (as I instantiate it the same way)

Answer (score 0):

I think price is not printed well, because Magento trying to get price, based on category we are on. But as you unserstand - home page is not a category.

You can try to add next code in your template:

```
if(!Mage::registry('current_category')) { 
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($store->getRootCategoryId());
    Mage::register('current_category', $root_category);
}
```

If it will not help - you can try to set Category on product level like

```
$_product->setCategory($root_category);
```

before `getPriceHtml` call

Comment: I don't think this is the issue as the default magento behaviour is to display price like it is being displayed on the home page currently, so it's using default behaviour rather than my extensions behaviour - but it isn't actually erroring.

Comment: Then, I think you'll need to use some standard magento widgets or blocks to put products on home page. I can recommend this one https://github.com/dio5/magento-multiproducts-widget, which allow to select any number of products and put them on CMS page